# Python: Cluster pickled files of images (over 35.000) each containing unique rgb codes

Tags: python, image-processing, cluster-analysis, pickle, rgb

I have a huge amount of pickled data of over 35.000 images. Each file represents one image and contains the unique rgb codes of all pixels and how often they appear.

In the format:

(235,33442;45,9452;2,765..) etc.

For my analysis I'd like to cluster all the images (pkl files), to see if there is a cycle or trend. Therefor, is it possible to cluster all files in one go, taking all data points and the amount of times they are visible per file in consideration? And do you have any tips to do so?

If I have not given enough info for the question to be answered please let me know!

Lots of thanks from a person who started just a month ago with programming:)

Comment: What do you mean with "cluster" here?

Comment: I hope I'm not wrong, but I thought I could use kmeans (or if it takes not to much time mean shift) in order to find if there is a pattern. The images are of fashionshows, using multiple masks I now have lists of only the clothes part of each image. I want to research if there is a cycle of returning colour groups to see if colour trends in fashion can be predicted.

Comment: K-means can't use this data type. This will be a rather challenging task, you'll need to read several books and tutorials. This too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've chosen to load the files in the directory, add them together and transform to a single csv file, inwhere each row contains the data of a pickle file. This makes it a lot easier.